# AtLeastOnceDelivery doesn't work with ask in akka-persistence?

Tags: scala, akka, akka-persistence

I was using use Akka and send messages using ask method

```
val future: Future = actor ? msg
```

But when I tried to replace that actor to `PersistentActor with AtLeastOnceDeliveryLike`, the future is never complete and fall down with timeout.

Is it possible to use Akka Persistent Actor with ask method?

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't imagine that would work, since `actor` would have to do whole [`delivery` / `confirmDelivery` dance](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/persistence.html#At-Least-Once_Delivery) in its reply. I suppose it's probably possible to create an `ask`-like pattern that would abstract that away, but it seems like there'd be a question of which side(s) of the ask have at-least-once-delivery semantics, as well as the specifics of the bookkeeping.